# Bold titledBorder

Tags: java, swing

I tried doing

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.font", Font.BOLD);
contentPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Client Downloader"));
```

But it's not making it bold. It just looked spaced apart.

Is that the wrong way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mark the question as accepted, but the comment says its not working. I would agree it should not be working.

```
Font.BOLD
```

is not a Font. It is a property of a Font. If you want to change the font you can do:

```
TitledBorder border = new TitledBorder(...);
border.setTitleFont( border.getTitleFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC) );
```

I added the italic just to show you the code works, since it appears to me that in the Metal LAF the default is for a Bold font.

Comment: +1 Interestingly, some L&F demos explicitly turn off Metal's use of bold fonts, e.g. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemo2Project/src/components/FileChooserDemo2.java

Comment: Thanks for a working reply. =) I used a different font to get it to work: 
 UIManager.put("TitledBorder.font", new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));

Answer (score 3):

Set the font when you create the border instead.  Something like:

```
 new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 1), "Client Downloader",
                                 TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, Font.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code change font or font size what u said in question.

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put( "TitledBorder.font", new javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource( new Font( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 12 ) ) ) ;
```

TitledBorder seems to have a constructor where you can specify the font >>>

```
public TitledBorder(Border border, String title, int titleJustification, int titlePosition, Font titleFont)
```

Creates a TitledBorder instance with the specified border, title, title-justification, title-position, and title-font.

Parameters:
border - the border
title - the title the border should display
titleJustification - the justification for the title
titlePosition - the position for the title
titleFont - the font for rendering the title

And even the color:

```
public TitledBorder(Border border, String title, int titleJustification, int titlePosition, Font titleFont, Color titleColor)
```

Creates a TitledBorder instance with the specified border, title, title-justification, title-position, title-font, and title-color.

Parameters:
border - the border
title - the title the border should display
titleJustification - the justification for the title
titlePosition - the position for the title
titleFont - the font of the title
titleColor - the color of the title

Answer (score 1):

Even createTitledBorder has:

```
public static TitledBorder createTitledBorder(Border border, String title, int titleJustification, int titlePosition, Font titleFont, Color titleColor)
```

Parameters:
border - the Border object to add the title to
title - a String containing the text of the title
titleJustification - an integer specifying the justification of the title -- one of the following:

```
 TitledBorder.LEFT 
TitledBorder.CENTER 

TitledBorder.RIGHT 
TitledBorder.LEADING 
TitledBorder.TRAILING 
TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION (leading)
```

titlePosition - an integer specifying the vertical position of the text in relation to the border -- one of the following: 
`

```
TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP 
TitledBorder.TOP (sitting on the top line) 
TitledBorder.BELOW_TOP 
TitledBorder.ABOVE_BOTTOM 
TitledBorder.BOTTOM (sitting on the bottom line) 
TitledBorder.BELOW_BOTTOM 
TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION (top)
```

`titleFont - a Font object specifying the title font
titleColor - a Color object specifying the title color

Returns:
the TitledBorder object