# Change the font of titled border in java swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I change the font for my titled border in a java swing application.
By changing the font,i mean ,changing font-style and font-color

Comment: read http://rahalsblogs.blogspot.com/2015/08/adding-font-styles-in-joptionpane.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. It a good practice to search before posting. This question is answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835042/bold-titledborder

Comment: When ever in doubt, check the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html#TitledBorder-javax.swing.border.Border-java.lang.String-int-int-java.awt.Font-java.awt.Color-)